# Directory.GetFiles() searchpattern

Tags: .net, regex

I have this basic code

```
Directory.GetFiles(filepath, "*.OUT")
```

In the filepath is a file named `Filename.OUT`

The above code finds that file fine.

Now, I rename the file by appending a UniqueID so that the file doesn't get picked up again.

`Filename.OUT6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF`

However, the file is STILL getting picked up by `Directory.GetFiles()`!

So, is the searchpattern (`*.OUT`) a regex pattern? If so, this makes sense.

The info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) doesn't seem to imply that it is. If not, is there a pattern I can use so that it doesn't get picked up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had to deal with this myself when working with a File System Monitor. Adding onto what MichaelPerrenoud said You can run all of your matches through a quick filter, like:

```
bool ExtensionOf ( String f, String targetext ) {
    return f.EndsWith( targetext );
}
```

If you don't need the flexibility of `targetext`, just replace it entirely with `".OUT"`

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior because in the document you linked it states:

> A searchPattern with a file extension of exactly three characters returns files having an extension of three or more characters, **where the first three characters match the file extension specified in the searchPattern.**

but in contrast it states:

> A searchPattern with a file extension of one, two, or more than three characters returns only files having extensions of exactly that length that match the file extension specified in the searchPattern.

so in your case you're going to **have** to filter out the results. I wish it were different. This is a problem for a lot of people, even myself included.

Answer (score 2):

You can strip-out (substring) input string by length of the guid:

```
string fileName = "Filename.OUT";
string seed = "6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF";
string input = fileName + seed;
string result = input.Substring(0, input.Length - seed.Length);
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(result);
Console.WriteLine(file.Extension);
```

and work with result as usually:

```
private static string StripSeed(string input)
{
    return input.Substring(0, input.Length - 36); // length of seed (guid)
}

Directory.EnumerateFile("*.*")
         .Select(p => StripSeed(p))
         .Select(f => new FileInfo(f))
         .Where(fi => fi.Extesnsion.Equals(".OUT", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

[Sandbox.](https://ideone.com/CjO5Sw)